# PHP Get Google Search Events by City

Tags: php, google-api

I'm trying to get city events from Google. For example a festival in Miami. If you type "Miami Events" in Google, a list of events swho up as tabs. I'm trying to get those using PHP. Not sure if this deals with the Calendar module.

[Here is an example.](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20google%20location%20events&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=off&q=miami%20events&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgEOLQz9U3SDMqM1CCs7S4nDNLKl3LUvNKih8xzmLkFnj5456w1ATGSWtOXmPsZORCkhfy4OLwyU9OLMnMzxOS4uKRgpuiwSDFxQXnSSkocfHOex3FL2q0xfiClhCn4METfIs23OwQTPVfe7fw07T_QoZcnGAzXRJLUoVUuASlePNSK0qCU4FiLomVxRqsUvxcqEI8ANMpGe_AAAAA)

how do you get the search results for city events through the Google API using php?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @u_mulder "how do you get the search results for city events through the Google API using php?"